# High frequency filter circuit design

Tags: inductor, high-frequency, emi-filtering

I am a trying to design a design an Electrosurgical interference suppression (ESIS) protection layer to filter out high frequency noise caused by Electrosurgical equipment during surgery. I am using ADAS1000, an electrocardiogram AFE.

I understand inductors can be used to block certain frequencies in a circuit.

My question is how do I go about designing a circuit to block 100kHz-5MHz noise on a electrode?( Single conduct line)

Comment: Is buying a filter from minicircuits.com out of the question?

Comment: If noise is 0.1M~5MHz what is the level and what is the signal? freq & level DC? and/or current ? so what is raw SNR and desired SNR out of filter? Always start a design problem with Specs like this in point form in question.  re you wanting to measure current , voltage or power?

Comment: What attenuation @ 100kHz  -3dB? -60db??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to measure cardio signals with a flat gain/phase response to 300 Hz and > 100 dB attenuation on  signals from arc noise from Electrosurgery > 100kHz.

I would chose RLD, STP cables ,active CM shield with CM chokes this attenuates by balancing the input signal to cancel mutual coupling of high stray E-B fields [V/m, A/m]

If your noise is less , pls specify.

I chose a 6th order RLC 10kHz filter, This would be differential "Pi filter" for differential signals with SMD Chokes with SRF assisting with attenuation.

Show below as single ended.

[image]

[Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%2065868806.91851612%0Ac%20256%20176%20256%20288%200%203.0000000000000004e-7%200%0Al%20192%20176%20256%20176%200%200.0022%200%0Aw%20384%20176%20448%20176%200%0Ar%20448%20176%20448%20288%200%20120%0Ag%20256%20288%20256%20304%200%0Ag%20448%20288%20448%20304%200%0AO%20448%20176%20496%20176%200%0A170%20192%20176%20160%20176%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AB%20384%2048%20448%20272%201%20Box%0AB%20256%20128%20320%20352%201%20Box%0Ac%20320%20176%20320%20288%200%201.2000000000000002e-7%200%0Al%20256%20176%20320%20176%200%200.0022%200%0Ag%20320%20288%20320%20304%200%0AB%20320%20128%20384%20352%201%20Box%0Ac%20384%20176%20384%20288%200%204e-8%200%0Al%20320%20176%20384%20176%200%200.001186806147028663%200%0Ag%20384%20288%20384%20304%200%0Ac%20192%20128%20256%20128%200%203e-11%200%0Ac%20256%20128%20320%20128%200%203e-11%200%0Ac%20320%20128%20384%20128%200%201.2e-10%200%0Aw%20384%20128%20384%20176%200%0Aw%20192%20128%20192%20176%200%0Aw%20256%20128%20256%20176%200%0Aw%20320%20128%20320%20176%200%0Ax%2046%20226%20222%20229%200%2024%20AIAP-01-222K-T%0Ax%20180%2087%20456%2090%200%2014%20Top%20Caps%20are%20due%20to%20SRF%20(Do%20not%20populate)%0A)

More practical L Values [image]

[image]

Comment: 5 MHz interference will probably get through those mH inductors. Less inductance and more parallel capacitance would be my advice.

Comment: I considered that @Andyaka and made use of the SRF to further attenuate with the load RC shunt values it works fine.  Much higher C, lower L values require lower R value (<50) then the INA cannot drive it.  This is a passive front end to avoid saturating INA. But active filters might work too.  SRF's from 0.5M to 2MHz are possible and shown with P/N.